# For-each function. Do something with 2 first, then something else with the rest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code, and i need to do something with the first 2 ojects and then something else with the rest, but how?
I get data from `<tr data-name='test' data-price='2' data-one='blabla' ...`

```
data = $(this).data();
html_option = "<table id='Unit_Options_Table'>";
// Do some thing with the first 2 
$.each(data, function(option, cost) { // Then do something with the rest
  html_option += "<tr>" +
          "<td class='Unit_Options_Name_td'>" + option + "</td>" +
          "<td class='Unit_Options_Cost_td'>" + cost + "</td>" +
          "</tr>";
});

html_option += "</table>";
```

Comment: `each`, as the name clearly states, does something with *each* element. So you cannot use it here, obviously.

Comment: Are you looping over an array or an object?

Comment: @bfavaretto data is an array of jQuery node objects - it'S defined in the first line of his code.

Comment: The whole concept of "the first two" doesn't reall make much sense, because you cannot rely on the order in which you'll get them back.

Comment: So the first argument passed to your callback (`option`) will be the index of each element in the array. Build an if statement based on that.

Comment: @Pointy - exactly, data attributes gotten with jQuery's data() method are treated the same way as internal data saved with data(), and that would be as an object (internally refered to as $.cache), so order is not guaranteed.

Comment: Ah, it's not an array...

Comment: @bfavaretto - nope, it's an object, as previously stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t really rely on the order of attributes. If you can change the markup, I’d recommend using JSON for your values:

```
<tr data-name="test" data-price="2" data-items='["blabla",…]'>
```

```
var name = this.dataset.name;
var cost = this.dataset.price;
var items = JSON.parse(this.dataset.items);

var option = $("<table>", { id: "Unit_Options_Table" });

// I’m not even sure where the loop belongs here
option.append(
    $("<tr>").append(
        $("<td>", { class: "name", text: name }),
        $("<td>", { class: "cost", text: cost })
    )
);
```

If not that, at least pick better names than `one`, `two`, etc. – you’re making it about as hard on yourself as possible by doing that.

In your specific situation as clarified in the comments, I’d do this:

```
<tr data-name="bla" data-cost="3" data-items='[{"name":"test","cost":20},…]'>
```

```
var data = $(this).data();
var items = $.parseJSON(data.items);

var option =
    $("<table>", { id: "Unit_Options_Table" })
        .append(
            $("<tr>").append(
                $("<th>", { text: data.name }),
                $("<th>", { text: data.cost })
            )
        )
        .append(
            $.map(items, function(item) {
                return $("<tr>").append(
                    $("<td>", { text: item.name }),
                    $("<td>", { text: item.cost })
                );
            })
        );
```

Comment: I have control over how the <tr> looks.
<tr data-name='bla' data-cost='3' data-oneName='test' data-oneCost='20'>

The data-name and data-cost is the "headline" and then after that i got some data pairs like "data-oneName & data-oneCost".
Using your eksample how would i pair those in your <tr>?

Comment: @DennisSødalChristensen: I added a specific example – give that a try.

Comment: Trying to get it to work, but get an error from jQuery:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u

I made a small test script here, can u see whats wrong?
http://pastebin.com/96YUWpv1

Comment: @DennisSødalChristensen: Well, you’re missing a closing `]` in the data attribute, and there is no `this` where you’re calling `$(this)`.

Comment: Think its this line that cause the problem var items = $.parseJSON(data.items);

Comment: @DennisSødalChristensen: Could you please post your updated HTML? It sounds like you’re still selecting the wrong element.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.each`, you'll find it much easier.

```
doSomething(data[0], data[1]);
for (var i = 2; i < data.length; ++i) {
    doSomethingElse(data[i]);
}
```

Forcing yourself to use a convenience function isn't very convenient...

Comment: Note that jQuery's each method iterates all kinds of stuff, unlike a for loop !

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn´t

```
option
```

be the index if you are iterating over an array ?

so it should be as simple as

```
$.each(data, function(option, cost) { 
  if(option < 2){
     //do something with first two
  }else{
     html_option += "<tr>" +
          "<td class='Unit_Options_Name_td'>" + option + "</td>" +
          "<td class='Unit_Options_Cost_td'>" + cost + "</td>" +
          "</tr>";
 }
});
```